# Hazelcast doesn't support local file storage

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Is there a way I can make Hazelcast to use local file system as a persistent storage? I read the following link it kind of suggests I can't do it:

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.2/manual/html-single/index.html#loading-and-storing-persistent-data

The concept I am trying to use is: A synced local storage on a cluster mode. E.g. if something is stored on one node's local storage it will be synced through Hazelcast and will be updated on other nodes' local storage as well. Is it possible? I have really high hopes :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is correct, don't try to do this.

The key point is that one node cannot write to a place that others cannot access, which by definition includes local storage.

Imagine a multi-node cluster, one node per host. Node 1 may have ownership of Entry *X* and write it via a `MapStore`. Nodes may join or leave the cluster, triggering data re-balancing. This might mean the node that has ownership of Entry *X* is now node 2. If node 2 can't access the local disk of node 1, then you can't get back the data stored.

Comment: :( ya that sounds more appropriate. Thank you :)